# Large decimail value Support in Textview

Tags: java, android

Large decimal value not Support in my Android application Store 1003477937.00 value but output is 1.003477937E9 but not same right format value.

Comment: post your code ..what you tried?

Comment: String totalmoney = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(winmoney) + Double.parseDouble(joinmoney));

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the decimal into a string and print as output.

```
double d = 12.3;   
String s = String.valueOf(d);  
textView.setText(s);
```